# ValueError: Input 0 of layer simple_rnn_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 50]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to tensor flow and i am trying to build a multivariate (two features for each time step) multi step (forecast 12 time step in the future) forecast model.

I created tensorflow  data set  to feed it to my model: 
When i print the shape of my data set, i find the following:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, None, 2), (None, None)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

This is what i understand:

```
(None, None, 2) = Input tensor "features" : (batchSize, Timesteps input, Features by time step)

(None, None) =Output Tensor "label" (batchSize, future forecsated time steps )
```

I follow up by creating my model as following :

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
model = keras.models.Sequential([
  keras.layers.SimpleRNN(50),
  keras.layers.SimpleRNN(100),
  keras.layers.Dense(12),
])
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.5e-6, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss="mae",
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["mae"])
```

When i fit the model

```
model.fit(train_set, epochs=5,
          validation_data=valid_set)
```

I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer simple_rnn_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 50]
```

I do understand that SimpleRNN layer is expecting a 3  dimension tensor.  But i think that my input has this dimension. 
Thanks a lot for the help. 
If you need me to share with you how i am creating my dataset, i would gladly do it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was coming form the second layer not the first one. Basically, the activation of the first layer issue a vector rather than a sequence, so it will have a rank of 2, eg: (a, b). But the second layer requires a three dimension input. TO solve this i added the return_sequences=True in the first layer of RNN.

Answer (score 1):

If `train_set` is a `numpy` array, pass `train_set.reshape((1,50))` to `model.fit()`

```
model.fit(train_set.reshape((1,50)), epochs=5,
      validation_data=valid_set)
```

Then you wouldn't need to apply `return_sequences=True` to the first RNN cell either.